# Keyboard shortcut to switch user accounts

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to quickly **switch user accounts** with a shortcut combination, something similar how a session can be ended by `Ctrl + Alt + Del` or locking the screen by `Ctrl + Alt + L` ?

(I'm using Unity, 11.10)

Answer (score 4):

In the latest Ubuntu LTR (18.04 - bionic) I've noticed that you can use CTRL+ALT+F2 / CTRL+ALT+F3 for instance to directly switch to the session of connected users. I'm not sure if it works for users without a current session nor if it extends to other TTYs as more users are connected...

There is also CTRL+ALT+F1 to display the login screen with all users listed.

*Although those TTY used to be terminals I have to admit this is quite useful now that many people mainly work on a GUI...*

Answer (score 2):

You can open the settings for shortcuts:
System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
and add a custom shortcut to start the gdmflexiserver.
After that you can switch with the shortcuts strg+alt+F7 and strg+alt+F8